# why doesn't logcat rotate log files properly?

Tags: android

According to [Android's documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html), logcat should (by default) create 4 output (log) files and redirect the output every 16 kb. However, when I enter the following command:

```
    logcat -f somefile.log
```

it creates four files none of which goes beyond 1 kb. And in case of the following command:

```
    logcat -r 25 -n 2 -f somefile.log
```

guess what? the same number of files and the same 1 kb limitation for each one!!!

Where am I wrong?

**NOTE:**
I am not using adb. I'm using that command to collect log files for my app and to send those files to an email when needed. And yes, there's plenty of space on my sdcard.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that you have the latest version of `adb`, it is 1.0.31 as of this writing.

   adb version
2. Make sure that there is enough free space in target's `sdcard`

That said, following are working as expected on my end:

```
adb logcat -f /sdcard/log.log
```

Generated 522KB of log file in target device's sdcard in 2 minutes.

```
adb logcat -f /sdcard/log.log -r
```

Generated 5 files in target device's sdcard in 2 minutes:

- log.log (4.15KB, that's due to cancelling logcat)
- log.log.1 (exactly 16KB)
- log.log.2 (exactly 16KB)
- log.log.3 (exactly 16KB)
- log.log.4 (exactly 16KB)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not using adb. I'm using that command to collect log files for my app and to send those files to an email when needed. And yes, there's plenty of space on my sdcard.

Comment: does rotation mean the files are rotated so that they take turns being over written?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a bug in Android 4.4:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72749
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72867

The fix review is here: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/100328